# Why below code is not able to unblock SIGINT signal

Tags: c, signals, process-management, ipc, system-programming

I am trying my hand on Linux Signals. Where I have created a scenario mentioned below:

1. Initially block all `SIGINT` signals using `sigprocmask()`.
2. If sender send `SIGUSR1` signal then unblock `SIGINT` for rest of the process life.

However first step is successfully implemented but not able to unblock (or change) process mask using `sigprocmask()`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

sigset_t block_list, unblock_list;

void sigint_handler(int sig)
{
        printf("Ouch!!\n");
}

void sigusr1_handler(int sig)
{
        sigemptyset(&unblock_list);
        sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &unblock_list, NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int count;

    signal(SIGINT, &sigint_handler);
    signal(SIGUSR1, &sigusr1_handler);

    sigemptyset(&block_list);
    sigaddset(&block_list, SIGINT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &block_list, NULL);

    for(count=1; ;++count)
    {
            printf("Process id: %ld\t%d\n", (long)getpid(), count);
            sleep(4);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

---

```
$kill -n SIGINT <pid>

$kill -n SIGUSER1 <pid> //This call should unblock sigint_handler() for rest of the process life, but it is only unblocking for one time. Everytime I have call $kill -n SIGUSER1 <pid> to unblock SIGINT.
```

Note: Error handling has been removed for simplicity.

Comment: You should never use `signal(2)`, but always `sigaction(2)`, and you should __never__ call `printf()` (or any other non signal safe function) from a signal handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel will restore the signal mask upon returning from a signal handler. This is specified by the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_sigmask.html#tag_16_459_08):

> When a thread's signal mask is changed in a signal-catching function
>        that is installed by `sigaction()`, the restoration of the signal mask
>        on return from the signal-catching function overrides that change
>        (see `sigaction()`). If the signal-catching function was installed
>        with `signal()`, it is unspecified whether this occurs.

On Linux, `signal(2)` is just a **deprecated** compatibily wrapper for `sigaction(2)`, and that does also occur when using `signal(2)`.